# Como fazer uma consulta pra obter as datas de acordo com os dias de semana?

Tags: mysql

Como fazer uma determinada consulta no MYSQL pegando as datas de acordo com o dia da semana?

Por exemplo:

```
+-------+---------------------+
| id    | created_at          |
+-------+---------------------+
| 49185 | 2015-02-19 02:35:10 |
| 49186 | 2015-09-03 06:22:51 |
| 49190 | 2015-05-27 03:09:28 |
| 49191 | 2015-09-04 01:32:00 |
| 51876 | 2016-04-18 16:52:14 |
| 51880 | 2016-06-23 06:03:34 |
| 51881 | 2016-06-23 07:02:01 |
| 51882 | 2016-06-24 07:18:10 |
| 51883 | 2016-07-12 13:17:33 |
| 51885 | 2016-09-28 07:28:26 |
| 51886 | 2016-10-27 06:35:25 |
| 51887 | 2016-12-07 14:59:44 |
+-------+---------------------+
```

Nesse exemplo, como eu poderia retornar apenas as datas que fossem referentes ao sábado ou domingo?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Basta usar

```
WHERE DAYOFWEEK( data ) = dia_desejado
```

Sendo que os dias da semana são numerados de 1 (domingo) a 7 (sábado).

Aplicando ao seu caso:

```
SELECT campos FROM tabela WHERE DAYOFWEEK( data ) IN ( 1, 7 );
```

Manual:

> https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_dayofweek